# Dictionary of dictionaries loses its value

Tags: c#, dictionary

```
        Dictionary<string, string> f = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>> lines = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>();

        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            lineArr = line.Split(',');
            int x = 0;
            foreach (string field in lineArr)
            {
                f.Add(keys[x], field);
                x++;
            }
            lines.Add(lineIndex, f);
            f.Clear();
            lineIndex++;
```

Dictionary f is temporary and I want to store its value inside another Dictionary, but once I Clear() it the value in Dictionary lines gets lost, I guess it delivers some kind of reference. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You are quite right, it's putting a reference to the dictionary inside of the other dictionary, not a copy of it.  The answer describes how to deal with this behavior.

Comment: Any particular reason why you're using `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>` instead of `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`?

Answer (score 8):

Move the declaration of `f` inside your loop. Then you won't have to empty it each time and the reference remains intact:

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>> lines = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>();

while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> f = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    lineArr = line.Split(',');
    int x = 0;
    foreach (string field in lineArr)
    {
        f.Add(keys[x], field);
        x++;
    }
    lines.Add(lineIndex, f);

    lineIndex++;
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `f` holds a reference to a `Dictionary<string, string>` object. When you add it to another dictionary, you're not creating a new object, only another reference to the same object.

I'd highly recommend just going with `f = new Dictionary<string, string>()` as the path of least resistence here.